# Looping through my PHP result using Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object, get

I have searched the posts, and I can't get anything to work with this.

I'd love some help with the solution, but even more so, if anybody has a few minutes, could you please explain how you dig down into array of objects? I've had about 5 different formats I've sent this query across to jquery with, and my biggest problem is that I do not know how to start digging into the array/object. i.e. I'm going to access the first element like this, and now that I have that, I'm going to get the second element like this...etc.

The current layout of my object/array is set up so that each object has an array. My thinking is, the object is the row, and the array is the fields. I set it up as an associative array, because I thought I could access everything easier, but my problem is I am just reading posts, and guessing really. I'd love a concrete explanation, so that I could access any type of object/array at any time and never have to ask again.

```
{
    "myArray1":
    {
         "Caption" : "First Caption",
         "Message" : "First Message",
         "Post_date" : "2013-08-02 18:24:33",
         "Name: "Author"
    },
    "myArray2":
    ....
```

This is my PHP.

```
 while($rRow = mysqli_fetch_array($selResult))
      {
          $row = Array();
          foreach($fldArray as $fld)
          {
             $row[$fld] = $rRow[$fld];
          }
          $count = $count + 1;
          $output["myArray".$count] = $row;
      }
      $output = json_encode($output);
      echo $output;
```

Comment: There is no array there. Those are simply nested objects.  Once you parse from JSON into a javascript object, you would access it like: `obj.myArray1.Caption`,`obj.myArray2.Message`, etc. Are you actually trying to make arrays and not objects? If so, you should show your PHP code to receive feedback on what is going wrong there.

Comment: I updated to show PHP...I am trying to find the best solution to take my results and send them to javascript and then put them in an HTML table.

Comment: The thing with JSON/javascript is that there is no concept of an associative array like there is in PHP.  So associative arrays are automatically converted to objects in the `json_encode()` process.

Comment: If you simply changed `$output["myArray".$count] = $row` to `$output[] = $row` then you would end up with an array of objects which probably makes more sense (unless you actually attach meaning to `myArrayX` naming convention). In this case, once you parse JSON into javascript (this time it make an array), you would access like `array[0].Caption`,`array[1].Message`, etc.

Comment: I tried - console.log(data.myArray1.Caption); and it says data.myArray1 is undefined. Data is what I receive in the callback function. I know data has the results, because when I print the entire variable to the console, it prints out. I will try changing my PHP as you stated.

Comment: Well, now you should show your javascript so it can be understod how you are retrieving and parsing the JSON data.

Comment: Yup, I think I got it from here. Thanks very much. Sometimes I get so caught up in trying so many different things, that I end up with a big mess up in my head.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I forgot to parse my JSON string back into an object, which is why I couldn't access anything.

Mike Brant's answered also helped a lot.

Thanks.